# Resolving "Permission Denied" Error for NGINX Connecting to Node.js Application on SELinux-Enabled System:

Tags: node.js, permissions, hosting, permission-denied, almalinux

> Connect() to 127.0.0.1:3000 failed (13: Permission denied) while
> connecting to upstream

I encountered a "Permission denied" error when NGINX tried to connect to my Node.js application running on port 3000 on an SELinux-enabled system. After some troubleshooting, I managed to resolve the issue by adjusting SELinux policies. Here's how I did it

1. Check SELinux Status:
   Verify that SELinux is enabled and enforcing on your system:

   **sestatus**
2. Review SELinux Denials:
   Check the SELinux audit logs for any denials related to NGINX attempting to connect to the Node.js application:

   **sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied**
3. Generate SELinux Policies:
   Use the audit2allow tool to generate SELinux policies based on the denials found in the audit logs:

   **sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied | audit2allow -M nginx_connect**
4. Load the SELinux Policy:
   Load the generated policy module into SELinux:

   **sudo semodule -i nginx_connect.pp**
5. Check SELinux Status:
   Verify that the new policy has been loaded successfully:

   **sudo semodule -l | grep nginx_connect**
6. Restart NGINX:
   After adjusting SELinux policies, restart NGINX to apply the changes:

   **sudo systemctl restart nginx**

This works for me